# mdx cross join a dimension and measure

Tags: mdx

I am new to MDX, looking at this query, why item(0) in the cross join in the [Top Product Sales] returns just Internet Sales Amount? Isn't the cross join supposed to return a set of (Product, Internet Sales Amount)? So why item(0) returns internet sales amount but not product?

```
    WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[Top Product Sales] AS
    {
    EXISTING
    TopCount(
    [Product].[Product].[Product].Members,
    1,
    ([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
    ) *
    {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
    }.Item(0)
    ,FORMAT_STRING="Currency"

    SELECT
    {
    ([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]),
    ([Measures].[Top Product Sales])
    } ON COLUMNS,
    {
    ([Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2005]),
    ([Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2006]),
    ([Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2007]),
    ([Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2008])
    } ON ROWS
    FROM [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

If I run the following query, I get a set from both dimensions (product and Internet Sales Amount), which makes sense to me, but why the above cross join return only Internet Sales Amount?

```
    WITH
    set x AS
    { 
    TopCount(
    [Product].[Product].[Product].Members,
    1,
    ([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
    ) *
    {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
    }

    SELECT
    {} ON COLUMNS,
    x ON ROWS
    FROM [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the `Item(0)` in your query returns a tuple consisting of a product and a measure. But  your first `SELECT` statement does not use that tuple, but `[Measures].[Top Product Sales]`, which is not a tuple, but a member of a single hierarchy, the measures hierarchy. You defined it in the `WITH` clause to deliver *the value of* the tuple each time it is evaluated, but not being an alias of the tuple. Using any expression in a `WITH MEMBER` clause converts it to a simple member.

In Analysis Services, you can only create members and sets, but not tuples in a `WITH` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't answer my question. My question was why Item(0) returns only the the measure not the top product or other? By definition Item function 'Returns a tuple from a set'. The tuple returned here is (product,Internet sales amount), so why in this scenario it only returns Internet sales amount?

Comment: @thotwielder Actually, I answered your question: `Item(0)` returns a tuple, but using that in a `WITH MEMBER` clause converts the tuple to a simple member.

Comment: That seems to be some kind of hidden rule because I can't find it documented anywhere.